# Latex on chemical reaction

Tags: chemfig

There is some problem with my code. It don't show Mg(OH)X correctly and arrow passes to reactant sites also

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    \schemestart
     \chemname{\chemfig{HC~CH}}{Acetylene}
     \arrow{->[Red Hot \chemfig{Cu} tube][400C]}
     \chemname{\chemfig{**6(------)}}{Benzene}
     \+ \chemfig{Mg (OH) Cl}
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

It gives me output like these :(
[image]

Clearly they are not aligned and the arrow length is very short and how to show degree at 400 degree celcius below arrow and how to display Mg(OH)X correctly .

Thank YOU :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \schemestart
     \chemname{\chemfig{HC~CH}}{Acetylene}
     \arrow(.{15.5}--){->[Red Hot \chemfig{Cu} tube][\SI{400}{\celsius}]}[0,2,]
     \chemname{\chemfig{**6(------)}}{Benzene}
     \arrow{0}[,0] \+ \chemfig{Mg {(OH)} Cl}
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

### Remarks

- For units,such as degree Celsius, use the [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package. In your concrete case I used `\SI{400}{\degreeCelsius}`.
- `\arrow` admits an optional argument with three values: angle, length coefficient and style, so I used `[0,2,,]` (i.e., angle=0, double the length and no style modification).
- I used an extra pair or braces arround `(OH)`, as in `\chemfig{Mg {(OH)} Cl}` (I am not sure if this is the desired result, though).
- An invisible arrow `\arrow{0}[,0]` was used so that "+ Mg(OH)Cl" is vertically aligned with the arrow to the left.
- To improve the vertical alignment with the acetylene, the anchor specification `(.{15.5}--)` was used for the `\arrow` (thanks to **clemens** for [`his comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251566/latex-on-chemical-reaction/251569?noredirect=1#comment599976_251569)).

Comment: Thanks , This is what exactly i want :)  And your explanation is very good i understand every thing now :)

Comment: Would it be possible to adjust the vertical alignment of the last bit?

Comment: @egreg I guess so; you mean align the elements in such a way that "+ Mg(OH)Cl" vertically aligns with the middle of the Benzene, right? When I return home I'll do it.

Comment: At least aligned with the arrow at the left side.

Comment: A better alignment with the acetylene can be achieved by giving an anchor to `\arrows(<name1>.<anchor1>--<name2>.<anchor2>)` (where all `<name>`s and `<anchor>`s are optional). Here `15.5` seems about right: `\arrow(.{15.5}--){->[Red Hot \chemfig{Cu} tube][\SI{400}{\celsius}]}[,2]`

Comment: @clemens Yes, that improves the vertical alignment. I've updated my answer. Thanks.